# Couchbase, performance drop from single node to three node cluster

Tags: .net, configuration, connection, nodes, couchbase

I've been working on trying to put together a POC in work for using Couchbase as the storage for a service in work.  I currently have three instances of Couchbase running on 3 vm's with boot2docker.  With current configuration file on a single node, using wrk benchmarking tool it can get 2245.01 req/sec, however when I add two more nodes the req/sec drops down as low as 50req/sec.  I have been changing configurations and searching them internet to no avail for the last while.  Would anyone know any reasons as to why the drop in performance when the nodes increase?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to add in the BucketConfiguration a

```
PoolConfiguration = new PoolConfiguration
      {
        MaxSize = 10,
        MinSize = 5,
        SendTimeout = 12000
      }
```

For example :

```
var config = new ClientConfiguration
{
  Servers = new List<Uri>
  {
    new Uri("http://192.168.56.101:8091/pools"),
    new Uri("http://192.168.56.102:8091/pools"),
    new Uri("http://192.168.56.103:8091/pools"),
    new Uri("http://192.168.56.104:8091/pools"),
  },
  UseSsl = true,
  DefaultOperationLifespan = 1000,
  BucketConfigs = new Dictionary<string, BucketConfiguration>
  {
    {"default", new BucketConfiguration
    {
      BucketName = "default",
      UseSsl = false,
      Password = "",
      DefaultOperationLifespan = 2000,
      PoolConfiguration = new PoolConfiguration
      {
        MaxSize = 10,
        MinSize = 5,
        SendTimeout = 12000
      }
    }}
  }
};
```

Did you made a volume redirection when launching the containers? There are some bugs with boot2docker, not good to do a benchmark.

One last thing, do not open many threads on the same subject ... [your last one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46602403/pointers-on-improving-couchbase-configuration/46608646#46608646)